# Is there a shortcut to switch panel instead of switching tab?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working on VSCode (last version) and sometimes I work with splitted panels.

I can't find a way to achieve same behavior than a `Ctrl + Tab` but for panels.

It currently sends me to another tab in the current panel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In vscode these are referred to as editor groups and can be switched between using either:

1. > <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>LeftArrow</kbd>/<kbd>RightArrow</kbd>

   to move focus through the editor groups. If you only have two active groups then this is equivalent to what you describe. This is the under `Focus Next Group`/`Focus Previous Group` in the keyboard shortcut settings so you could remap this to something else if you prefer.

**or**

2. > <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>/<kbd>2</kbd>/<kbd>3</kbd>

   To specify focus in editor group 1/2/3

Comment: Thanks a lot, these were exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: No problem :) Just so you know can use Ctrl+K, Ctrl+R to view a condensed keyboard shortcut reference at any time, full of handy tricks like this

Comment: ohoh ! More than perfect! Thanks again dude!